# [__NSDictionaryM allAttributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis, nsmutabledictionary, unrecognized-selector

For some reason, I continue to receive the "unrecognized selector sent to instance". My goal is to use values denoted as "lat,lon" to set the x, and y coordinates further creating an AGSPoint for use for a zoom method "ZoomToCrew".
The method in question is:

```
-(void)handlePodNotifications:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"PodInteraction"])
    {
        PodInteractionObject *interactionObject = [notification object];

        if([interactionObject.interactionName isEqualToString:@"ZoomToCrew"])
        {
            AGSGraphic *temp = (AGSGraphic *)interactionObject.interactionObject;

            double xcoord = [[temp valueForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
            double ycoord = [[temp valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
            AGSPoint *newPoint = [AGSPoint pointWithX:xcoord y:ycoord spatialReference:[AGSSpatialReference wgs84SpatialReference]];

            // [self.mapView.callout showCalloutAtPoint:newPoint forFeature:interactionObject.interactionObject layer:_featureLayer animated:YES];
            [self.mapView zoomToResolution:.2 withCenterPoint:newPoint animated:YES];

        }

    }
}
```

Thank You in advance for any help you may be able to offer!

Comment: The error means that even though you're trying to cast an NSMutableDictionary into an AGSGraphic object (i.e. `(AGSGraphic *)interactionObject.interactionObject`), it's still an NSMutableDictionary and does not have an allAttributes key.

Comment: (Whoops...by allAttributes "key" I mean property...)

Comment: Understandable, what would be the best way to accomplish this while ensuring all the attributes are maintained?

Comment: Thank you it's working, Check out the edits above!